# i want to obtain a attribute's value of an xml tag, which would be case insensitive using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

i want to obtain a value of xml attribute in XSLT1.0 which is case insensitive or we can say ignored case Tag, for example if we have a tag

```
 <Name></Name> or 
 <name></name> or 
 <nAME></nAME> etc
```

in every scenario our ***value-of select="name"*** should be obtain the value of this XML tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CommandList>
    <Name>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</Name>
    <name>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</name>
    <nAme>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</nAme>
    <nAME>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</nAME>
</CommandList>
```

***expected outcome :*** 
Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-Lufthansa-abc-def-Group

Comment: what have you done to try to obtain the tag, that is not working for you ?

Comment: @Lena i have nothing to get it in my mind

Comment: which programming language are you using to parse this xml ?

Comment: @Lena i have to get the result in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @Lena Bru, is there any way to achieve this thing??

Comment: Not sure about xslt 1.0 but isnt there also something like "//*[lower-case(name()) = 'name']"?

Comment: No @ChristianMosz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
     <xsl:for-each select="*[(translate(local-name(.), 'NAME', 'name')) = 'name']">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

see transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEaSv6

Comment: this will fail in the below condition 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CommandList>
        <Name>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</Name>
        <name>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</name>
        <nAme>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</nAme>
        <nAME>Lufthansa-abc-def-Group-</nAME>
        <sub>Mathematics</sub>
    </CommandList>

this code also gets the value of ***sub*** tag

Comment: actually i want to get the value of the **name** tag, either name tag comes like **Name** , or **nAmE** or **naME** or in any case.

if xml have 

     <Command>
          <nAme>sadik</nAme>
        <Command>
        OR
        <Command>
          <nAMe>sadik</nAMe>
        <Command>

then it should be access with 

    <xsl:value-of select="Command/name" />

Comment: This answer seems to misunderstand how translate() works.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelKay, for highlighting this, i miss that checking part in script.

Answer (score 0):

@Michael Kay
i tried it but not getting the result ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()" />
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="translate(name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')" select="." />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: See https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jz1Q1y8 for the correct implementation in XSLT 1.0. -- Note that this assumes all node names are using only the 26 listed characters.

Answer (score -1):

When you're starting with messy XML my recommendation is always to do a two-pass operation: first turn it into clean XML, then do the real processing. Clean XML definitely doesn't use mixed upper and lower case in tags.

Converting everything to lower case is easy enough:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="lower-case(name())">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="lower-case(name())" select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

The advantage of the two-pass approach is that the code for the first phase is reusable; you can put it into your processing pipeline whatever the subsequent processing is.

Comment: Sorry, I see you tagged it XSLT 1.0; in that case you need to use `translate(name(), 'ABCDE....', 'abcde....')` for the lower-case conversion.

Comment: turn xml into clean XML, is it mean you are saying about formation of XML or what?

Comment: Well, ideally you would change the code that generates the XML to produce something cleaner. But if you can't do that, then clean it up on arrival before doing any real processing on it.

Comment: i tried it but not getting the result https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986288/12504577